# Web API post method to send image

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, postman

I need to code a method in a WebAPI application where I need to send an Image, this is what I'm doing:

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostPicture(string xmit, int contactNum, [FromBody] byte[] picture)
    {
        Image img = null;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(picture))
        {
            img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        if (img != null)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I'm sending the byte[] into the body in the request the value of the picture parameter is always null.
I'm using Postman to test the method and the request body is being send as a **x-www-form-urlencoded**.
[image: Postman Test]
Could anyone help me to find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: that looks like base64 encoding. have you tried changing it (the parameter) to a string and then converting to byte array

Comment: @Nkosi No I didn't try that, I will do and I let you know. Thanks

Comment: Another option would be to remove the parameter and read it directly from the request `imageStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`

Comment: @Nkosi I change the code to get string parameters but it keeps getting null I really don't know why

Comment: I can not understand why someone could vote down a programming question without let people know why is the reason for, I don't see any problem in this question at all, who did please explain why? So the next time we don't make the same mistake

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm doing that right now, thanks

Comment: @Nkosi, I did this: `public async Task<Stream> PostPicture(string xmit, int contactNum)
        {
            var imageStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await Task.FromResult<Stream>(imageStream);
        }` But it didn't work, I don't know if the problem is how I'm making the request in Postman

Comment: That may be a possibility. you should recheck how you send it in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Nkosi, this solved the problem: `Another option would be to remove the parameter and read it directly from the request imageStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` actually it didn't work before because the way I was doing the request in Postman. Thanks again